# Does changing parameter and return types in a child class, means breaking SOLID design principles?

Tags: php, design-patterns, casting, liskov-substitution-principle

I am building an application which uses API to retrieve data from a third party source.
The data that is consumed needs to be formatted so I have decided to create an ConvertTypeInterface that forces child classes to  implement `convert($data)` method which will convert/format any data into any other format.

**ConvertTypeInterface**

```
interface ConverterTypeInterface
{
    public function convert($data);
}
```

Now the problem with this I think I might be breaking Liskov's Substitution principle by not forcing stricter types on parameters or return types, however in this case I can't use type hinting for a parameter or a return type because $data parameter can be anything: string, integer, object, array etc. same with the return type.

**Converter Example**

```
class ConvertToInteger implements ConverterTypeInterface
{
    public function convert($data)
    {
        return (int) $data;
    }

}
```

**Usage Example**

```
/* I have an array of data field names and type of conversion that should be made for that field,
 * I loop through each of the fields that need to be converted and based on a converter type conversion 
 * changes the value of that field.
 */
    foreach ($convertFields as $field=>$type){
       if(isset($this->converters[$type])) {
           $data[$field] = $this->converters[$type]->convert($data[$field]);
       }else {
           throw new \Exception("Converter type `".$type."`` doesn't exist");
       }
    }
```

**Question**

Is this breaking Liskov's substitution principle or another SOLID design principle? Is there a way to improve this ?

Comment: If you can put together a complete, working example of the design you're trying to improve, I would suggest posting it to https://codereview.stackexchange.com for feedback.